# Vue: Dynamic component using HTML elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to dynamic components in Vue and after reading the documentation, I am still unsure if I can use pure elements rather than just component name.  I want to have an `a` element if the prop `active` isn't true, otherwise use the `ModalComponent`.
I figure this can't work because then the props listed, like `foo`, wouldn't make sense on an `a` element.  Is there another solution?

```
//template

<component
    :is="this.active ? 'ModalComponent' : 'a'"
    :href="href"
    :foo="Test"
    :class="$style.container"
    ref="link"
  >
     <Avatar />
 </component>

//script 

import ModalComponent from '@/component/ModalComponent';
import Avatar from '@/component/Avatar';
```

Comment: dynamic components serve no purpose here because here you just want to choose between ModalComponent ( Component) and <a> (html element). You can do this with just v-if-else

Comment: If you have multiple components and wanted to render those based on some flag then go for dynamic components

Comment: @Amaarrockz if I used `v-if` though, wouldn't I have to rewrite everything nested under again?  `<RootComponent v-if="foo> <SubComponent /> < /RootComponent>  <AlternativeRootComponent v-else> <SubComponent /></AlternativeRootComponent>`
If I used v-if to determine the main component, I feel like I'd be writing everything nested under that over, the examples case, `<Avatar/>`

Comment: Having alternate root components is not a better design., instead you need to have alternate only for subcomponents